# angularjs - how do I call a standard filter from within a filter I define?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Angular comes with a standard filter called "filter".  I am defining my own filter and the first step I would like to take is to filter my list using the included "filter" filter -- how can I access it from within a new filter I am defining?

Answer (score 1):

Inject and use Angular's filter service:

```
var existingFilter = $filter('filtername'); 
var result = existingFilter('some_param');
```